# Math Functions - Trigonometry

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been dabbling in the nether realms between Trigonometry and Python, and gave birth to this demon:

```
self.angleA = degrees(acos(((b**2)+(c**2)-(a**2))/(2*b*c)))
self.angleB = degrees(acos(((c**2)+(a**2)-(b**2))/(2*c*a)))
self.angleC = degrees(acos(((a**2)+(b**2)-(c**2))/(2*a*b)))
self.area = 1/2**a*b*degrees(sin(self.angleC))
```

Python gives an error:

```
self.angleA = degrees(acos(((b**2)+(c**2)-(a**2))/(2*b*c)))
    ValueError: math domain error
```

I think it has something to do with the whole degree/radian thing going on here. Any help?

`BUZZYSIN`

Comment: I also believe I have the whole trigonometric thing wrong. If so, is there any way to correct it?

Comment: what are you values for `a,b,c`?

Comment: note that for `acos(x)` to be valid, x has to be `-1<=x<=1`

Comment: @RNar, they are input in a triangle class as `self.sidea` etc. and then reassigned to a, b and c for simplicity.

I input 12 and 14 as a and b.

Comment: Also, to make it easier on yourself `self.angleC = 180 - (self.angleA + self.angleB)`.

Comment: You may want to use pdb to break just before the problematic line of code and poke around to see what's going on: `import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: Mathematically, you seem to be using the law of cosines correctly -- so there must be a problem with `a`, `b`, `c` --  such as a violation of the triangle inequality. Another possibility is that round-off error could cause the argument of `acos` to be over `1.0` even though mathematically it should be `1.0`. Just what values of `a,b,c` give the error?

Comment: @JohnColeman, the values that I entered were `a=12`, `b=14`, `c = ((a**2)+(b**2)-(2*a*b*degrees(cos(C))))**(1/2)`, where `c` is a given angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few trivial problems.  First, you're going to get killed by integer arithmetic if you're in that realm of Python.  Inject 2.0 for 2, in case it matters.  Did you test with simple cases, such as a 3-4-5 right triangle?

Second, your area formula is wrong; you raise 2 to a power.  Get rid of the extra asterisk.

Third, in your area calculation, you re-converted radians (actually degrees already) in to degrees.  You need to go the other way.  Also, you have to do this before you take the sin; the sine function takes degrees and returns a scalar, which you should not convert to another unit.

Finally, when you post, please make sure you give a complete example.  Your code, as given, doesn't run.  Here's my version and the output.

```
from math import *

a, b, c = 3, 4, 5

angleA = degrees(acos(((b**2)+(c**2)-(a**2))/(2.0*b*c)))
angleB = degrees(acos(((c**2)+(a**2)-(b**2))/(2.0*c*a)))
angleC = degrees(acos(((a**2)+(b**2)-(c**2))/(2.0*a*b)))
area = 0.5*a*b*sin(radians(angleC))

print angleA, angleB, angleC
print area
```

output

```
36.8698976458 53.1301023542 90.0
6.0
```

---

@John Coleman nailed your original problem, by the way.  I tried this code with input 3, 4, 20 -- and there's the math domain error.  Module math throws this when you try to take **acos** of an invalid number, one outside [-1.0, 1.0].

Comment: I dont understand whythe `radians()` method was used on the 4th line before last. Can you explain?

Comment: The trig functions work in radians.  When you originally computed arc-cosine, you converted to degrees.  To take the sine later, you have to convert back to radians.  You could also remove both conversions and work in radians.